# Excel Userform live time countdown

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a simple userform with a text label. I have put this code on activation of userform to run remaining time from target time. It is good once it runs, but it does not count down... Seconds do not flick down ... etc.

**Code**

```
Private Sub UserForm_activate()
targtime = DateValue("28 Jun 2018") + TimeValue("18:37:00")
remtime = targtime - Now
Me.Label1 = Int(remtime) & " Days " & Format(remtime - Int(remtime), "HH:MM:SS")
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in an endless loop and it would start ticking every second:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim remTime As Date

    While True
        remTime = DateValue("28 Jun 2018") + TimeValue("18:37:00") - Now
        Me.Label1 = Int(remTime) & " Days " & Format(remTime - Int(remTime), "HH:MM:SS")
        Me.Repaint
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
    Wend


End Sub
```

Comment: That crashed my userform.. I had to ctrl+break it. Also seconds did not tick down.

Comment: @OdaySalim - Still, making a ticking endless loop is expected to crash some time... You should come up with some logic when and how to stop.

Comment: I will be able to put together logical expressions to make it stop. What I am unable to do is make the clock tick...

Comment: @OdaySalim - in the updated code it is ticking. I have added `Me.Repaint` and the Waiting. Still, after some time enjoying the ticking, you'll have to stop it with Ctrl+Break.

Comment: Thanks - perhaps there is no need to make it tick per second. I would just do a countdown in days without a loop and not having to break it. Thanks